# python requests breaks with Jsondecodeerror :expecting value:char(0)

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use python to build a crawler, the wen provided me an API, but my breaks with Jsondecodeerror: expecting value: char(0). I wonder if you can provide me some suggestions. Many thanks!

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request as urlrequest
import requests
import json
import xlsxwriter

url = "http://wits.worldbank.org/API/V1/SDMX/V21/datasource/TRN/reporter/840/partner/000/product/all/year/2000/datatype/reported"
data = requests.get(url).json()
```

Then，it's broken by `json.decoder.JSONDecodeerrorError: Expecting Value: line 1 column 1 char(0)`

Comment: Are you sure the link is correct? what does it do when you access the link in browser?

Comment: That doesn't return JSON.  It returns XML.  You can either use an XML decoder, or see if there's an option you can specify to request JSON.

Comment: And, by the way, you would have discovered this yourself if you had taken the simple step of printing out what was returned to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "crawler", "wen", "breaks"? Just trying to understand

Comment: Or just by visiting that url

Answer (score 0):

requests.get(url).json() returns a JSON object of the result if the result was written in JSON format, if not it raises an error. Your url response is probably not in JSON format.

Comment: Many thanks!I should put a  "?json" at the end of URL.I'm sorry for my careless

Comment: No, the response is in XML format, you'll need to use a XML decoder.

Comment: @Bing please kindly accept the answer if it’s solved your issue so the question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

By trying to convert to json, you're expecting the request to return something in json format. Your error states that It's expecting a value (which is "`{`") at the very beginning of the file. However, upon visiting the website, you can easily find that it is not JSON but actually XML ([see source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FVAa.png)).

You can use an XML parser to parse this (read this [quick tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xml-parsing-python/) on how to parse XML) or find a different path where json is available.

Simply adding `?json` to the end of the URL *will not* convert the XML to JSON.